# Having trouble setting Remote Desktop Services Control permissions?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to power shell and I am trying to create a script that would create new users in Active Directory. Currently I am having trouble setting the Remote Desktop Services tab of the User. My code is below.

```
#Set Remote Control Settings Permissions  
        #I recieved Server is not operational error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/fail-to-configure-server-using-server-manager I think Invoke Set may not be the command I should use.
        
        $userpath = dsquery user -samid $username 
        $userpat = "LDAP://$userpath"
        $userp = [ADSI]$userpat
        $userp.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",2)
        $userp.setinfo()
        
        #Remote Desktop Services User profile profile path set to "\\documentsf\profiles\$username" THIS IS MESSING UP ERROR OCCURRS WITH INVOKE SET SAYING NOT SPECIFIED
         
        $userp.InvokeSet("terminalservicesprofilepath","\\documentsf\profiles\$username")
        $userp.setinfo()
```

Comment: Are you aware about the ActiveDirectory Module that's available for you to download?

Comment: Yes, however I don't know how to use the Active Directory module for Remote Control Settings Permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote control permissions are a little strange and work best with the ADSI method, which you're close to already. `dsquery` actually returns a string with quotes inside it, so you'll either need to strip those quotes first or use a different method - I prefer `Get-ADUser`:

```
$LdapUser = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADUser $username).distinguishedName
$User = [ADSI]$LdapUser
$User.InvokeSet("EnableRemoteControl",2)
$User.setinfo()
```

And to set the remote desktop services profile path for a user:

```
$User.invokeset("terminalservicesprofilepath","\\Server\Share\$username")
$User.SetInfo()
```

Comment: This worked for me to set the permissions however the remote desktop services User profile path was not set for the user. I received no errors it was simply not set?

Comment: @user16603959 My bad, I guess all the msTS attributes need the invokeSet methods. Try `$User.invokeset("terminalservicesprofilepath","\\Server\Share\$username")` and `$User.SetInfo()` instead?

Comment: That worked like a charm thank you for helping me out!